# SQL Developer Error ORA-04072 Invalid Trigger Type Issue

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I am trying to figure out why the code keeps giving me Error: ORA-04072: Invalid Trigger Type. On the Messages Tab it says "Compiled (With Errors) and on the Compiler Tab it says the Error number and the reason.

[image]

Code is:

```
create or replace TRIGGER trg_employee_salary_chk
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF SALARY ON EMPLOYEES 

declare

v_min_salary jobs.min.salary%type;
v_max_salary jobs.max_salary%type;

BEGIN

    select min_salary, max_salary
    into v_min_salary, v_max_salary
    from jobs
    where job_id = :new.job_id;
    
    if v_min_salary is not null and v_min_salary > :new.salary then
        raise_application_error(-20111, 'Salary too low');
    end if;
    
    if v_max_salary is not null and v_max_salary < :new.salary then
        raise_application_erro(-20111, 'Salary too high');
    end if;

END;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The raise_application_erro is an error in your trigger. Try to correct it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The raise_application_erro is an error in your trigger. Try to correct it.
2. You didn't write the "for each row" in your trigger.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, I was able to change your recommended changes. But now I have a lot more errors. 1. Error(8,14): PL/SQL: Item Ignored 2. Error(8,19): PLS-00302: component 'MIN' must be declared. 3. Error(13,5): PL/SQL: SQL Statement Ignored 4. Error(14,10): PLS-00320: The declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed 5. Error(15,5) PL/SQL: ORQ-00904:Invalid Identifier 6. Error(18.5) PL/SQL: Statement Ignored 7. Error(18,8) PLS-00320L The declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed.

Comment: Instead of v_min_salary jobs.min.salary%type; write v_min_salary jobs.min_salary%type;

Comment: Oh did not even see that, thank you so much for the help.